# Find the highest index set to true in std::bitset

Tags: c++

I'm using `std::bitset<9> deck` in my program. By default it initializes all bits to 0.

Somewhere in my code I'm doing: `deck.flip(index)` where `index` can be any number from `0-8` (bitset indexes).

Now what I need is to find the index of the `last` bit set to `true`.

E.g:

```
000100010 - bitset
876543210 - index
```

In this example the latest bit set to true is at index `5`. That is what I would like to find using `std::bitset`.

I have read the documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset and found no useful function to do this, and as a beginner I'm having a hard time figuring out, how can I do this?

(Sorry if question is poorly written, english is my second language)

Comment: Loop (manually) from end until you find a bit set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that only option is to iterate over bit set and find last bit set since bit set does not have support for iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <optional>

template <size_t N>
constexpr std::optional<int> find_last_index_of_bit_set(std::bitset<N> set)
{
    for (int i = set.size()-1; i > -1; --i) {
      if (set.test(i)) {
          return std::optional(i);
      }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main() 
{
    std::bitset<10> bitSet("000100010");

    auto pos = find_last_index_of_bit_set(bitSet);

    if (pos.has_value()) {
        std::cout << "Max index is: " << pos.value() << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "No bit set";
    }
}
```

Comment: Start from the end and stop as soon your found a set bit.

Comment: Good point, i've updated and also added optional as return type in case that there is no bit set

Answer (score 3):

Here's a gcc/clang specific way using the `__builtin_clzl()` intrinsic, which returns the number of leading 0 bits starting from the most significant:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
int msb(const std::bitset<N> &bs) {
  static_assert(N <= (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long)), "bitset is too big");
  auto n = bs.to_ulong();
  // C++20 will have std::countl_zero() but in the meantime:
  assert(n != 0); // clz is undefined if n is 0. Maybe return -1 in this case?
  return (CHAR_BIT * sizeof n) - __builtin_clzl(n) - 1;
}

int main() {
  std::bitset<9> bs;
  bs[1] = 1;
  bs[5] = 1;
  std::cout << "Highest set bit is " << msb(bs) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

will print `Highest set bit is 5`. This approach only works with bitsets equal or smaller than the number of bits in an `unsigned long`, of course (Though it can go up to `unsigned long long` with a few minor changes)

Answer (score 2):

<bitset> has nothing built in for this, but in C++20 you can reduce the problem to one for <bit>.

```
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// count leading zeroes in bitset<N>
template <size_t N> inline constexpr size_t countl_zero(std::bitset<N> x) {
  using bitsetN = std::bitset<N>;
  using ulong = unsigned long;
  using ullong = unsigned long long;
  constexpr size_t ulong_digits = std::numeric_limits<ulong>::digits;
  constexpr size_t ullong_digits = std::numeric_limits<ullong>::digits;

  // binary reduce until we have something <bit> can handle.
  size_t l_zero = 0;
  size_t digits = N;
  while (digits > ullong_digits) {
    const size_t half = digits / 2;
    const bitsetN high_bits = ~bitsetN(0) << half;
    if ((x & high_bits).any())
      x >>= half;
    else
      l_zero += half;
    digits -= half;
  }

  return digits > ulong_digits ? l_zero + std::countl_zero(x.to_ullong()) -
                                     (ullong_digits - digits)
                               : l_zero + std::countl_zero(x.to_ulong()) -
                                     (ulong_digits - digits);
}

template <size_t N> inline constexpr size_t bit_width(std::bitset<N> x) {
  return N - countl_zero(x);
}

int main(void) {
  constexpr size_t N = 9;
  using bitsetN = std::bitset<N>;
  {
    bitsetN bs("0");
    std::cout << bs << ":" << bit_width(bs) << std::endl;
  }
  {
    bitsetN bs("1");
    std::cout << bs << ":" << bit_width(bs) << std::endl;
  }
  {
    bitsetN bs("11");
    std::cout << bs << ":" << bit_width(bs) << std::endl;
  }
  {
    bitsetN bs("10000");
    std::cout << bs << ":" << bit_width(bs) << std::endl;
  }
  {
    bitsetN bs("101010000");
    std::cout << bs << ":" << bit_width(bs) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

output:

```
000000000:0
000000001:1
000000011:2
000010000:5
101010000:9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int setSetBit(int x, int y){

    bitset<32> _x(x);
    bitset<32> _y(y);
    string __x = _x.to_string();
    string __y = _y.to_string();
    __x.erase(0, __x.find('1'));
    __y.erase(0, __y.find('1'));
    cout << __x << ": " << __x.length() << " \n" << __y << ": "<< __y.length() << "\n";
}   

int main(){
    setSetBit(44, 3);
}
```

Output:

101100: 6
11: 2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).